# OneDrive / SharePoint - Remotely stop user's folder sync

Tags: azure, sharepoint, onedrive-for-business

I must be missing something, but I can't see any way to stop a certain SharePoint folder from syncing to a user's local OneDrive folder.

Our file servers are almost full because of two users who apparently have a whole site synced to their local OneDrive. And I can't reach them as they're both on vacation.

I have however opened the sharepoint admin center and I can browse their OneDrive, but can't in an easy way see neither folder sizes OR find the synced folder in their user folder. I do see they follow the site though, and I guess the site is being synced. But I can't find a way to remotely stop the sync. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you syncing one drive to your file servers?

Comment: The other way around. In SharePoint you can subscribe to a channel, or a set of folders and then sync those folders to your local OneDrive.

The problem is that the OneDrive repo is a local file server. And that is not my decision. The file servers are stored in an on-premise storage park